# I can´t get the friendlist from facebook C# SDK (Windows phone)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

i want to get the facebook friend's list from my application, but returns me data: []... empty! :(

the scenario it's this:

C#

```
 const string QueryToGetFbInfo = "me";
 const string QueryToGetFbPhoto = "me?fields=picture.width(200).height(200)";
 const string QueryToGetFriendList = "me/friends?fields=name,picture.width(100).height(100)";

private void btnFacebook_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
        FacebookSessionClient fbSession = new FacebookSessionClient("FB_APP_ID");
        fbSession.LoginWithApp("public_profile, user_friends, read_friendlists, email", "custom_state_string");
}

 private async void tbnShowfriends_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
 {
        FacebookSession session = SessionStorage.Load();
        FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(session.AccessToken);

        // Get Facebook FriendList
        dynamic friends = await client.GetTaskAsync(QueryToGetFriendList);

        //Get Facebook user info
        dynamic result = await client.GetTaskAsync(QueryToGetFbInfo);
        GraphUser user = new GraphUser(result);

        //Get profile picture from facebook
        dynamic result1 = await client.GetTaskAsync(QueryToGetFbPhoto);
        JsonObject json = result1.picture.data;
        var picture = (IDictionary<string, object>)json;

        ....
 }
```

Facebook App Config has the permissions... forgot some ?.. the new panel confuses me a little, Maybe I forgot something in the application settings...

[image: Facebook App]

when i select Api Graph, returns me, a friendlist, fine!
[image: friends]

but when I select my application, I do not return anything
[image]

What I forgot ?... how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: any final solution using v2.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

You authed Graph Explorer using API v1.0 which means that that app will get all your friends until 4/30/2014. You app you authed using v2.0 or v2.1 which means that you will only get friends that are also using the app

Comment: yeah, i read this at developers facebook portal, but my app its V2.1... so, i dont understand...  these versions are just for developers no ?, i mean, nobody use graph api, just us (dev)... or no ?.... i´m so confusse.... of my 305 friends, nobody use V2.1 ??

Comment: ohohoooo, ok, i understand, then it means that I can not get the list of all my friends?.... How do I get it?

Comment: That means that you can only get the friends that are using your app and not all friends